# Unable to use assign recordId to another property

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm building an LWC to quickly create a new contact and link it to an existing Account based upon the record page in which it lives.  I can create Contacts fine, but the linking isn't working.  Here's my code:

**JS file**

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class QuickCreateContactOnAccount extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    accountId = this.recordId;
}
```

**HTML file**

```
<template>
    <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Contact">
        <lightning-input-field field-name="FirstName" value={defaultName}></lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="LastName"></lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Email"></lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Mobile"></lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="AccountId" value={accountId}></lightning-input-field>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
    <p>The record id is {recordId}.</p>
    <p>The account id is {accountId}.</p>
</template>
```

When trying to default the AccountId to the value of recordId, I'm getting nothing.  I added some paragraph output and recordId is coming in ok but doesn't reassign to AccountId.  The output is:

The record id is: **18-character ID**
The account id is: **blank**

Comment: Any reason not to use a screen flow to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because your assignment occurs before construction, while the `@api` properties can't be set until after the construction process. That's a limitation of how JavaScript (and most object-oriented programming) works. To set the value, use a getter/setter property pair, like so:

```
@api set recordId(value) {
  this.accountId = value;
}
get recordId(value) {
  return this.accountId;
}
```

Note that you must use the `@api` decorator exactly once, either on the `get` or `set`, or it won't work correctly as a public property.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this by setting the accountId property in a ConnectedCallback lifecycle hook. The reason you'll be getting nothing at the moment is likely because you're trying to set the value before the @api annotated property is populated.

Something like the below should work:

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class QuickCreateContactOnAccount extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    accountId;

    connectedCallback(){
        this.accountId = this.recordId;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would not do that, myself, as you are assuming it is always used in a record page and that the ID never changes. I would make recordId a getter/setter property and have the setter set the accountId as well.